# How to refresh parent page from child page in asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a page showing all products in a gridview.
I have a link in the page clicking on it opens a modal window.
In the modal window there is a form to enter product and save.
When I fill the form and save product I need to make the parent page to be refreshed so that
the new product is listed in the gridview and a message will be shown in a label in the modal window. I need to refresh the product list page without closing the modal window.
How to do it?

Please help.

Comment: A modal will be part of the page, so you can't refresh what's under the modal without refreshing the modal too. If you're confusing modal with pop-up, then Alexander's answer will do the trick for you (:

Comment: you have not checked that your selected answer not working with mozilla browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refresh it with the following JavaScript:

```
window.opener.location.reload(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.opener.location.reload(true);
```

`true` makes sure that the page is reloaded from the server instead of the browser's cache.

This will work only if the second page was opened by the first page using javascript and not when you open a link in the first page in a new window - `window.opener` will be `null` in the later case. Even in the former case, Firefox will throw a 'permission denied' error if both pages are not from the same domain.

Comment: Just tested it on firefox with firebug. It works only if both pages are from same domain - otherwise you'll get a permission denied error.